# Unable to proactively install Microsoft teams app through Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to proactively install my Teams app, which is still in development and has not been fully published by Microsoft. I've installed it to my Teams org in the Teams admin center. When I try to install the app in the personal scope of my test user, I'm getting the following message (excluding my azure app id):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Forbidden",
        "message": "AAD App Id {My azure app ID} is not allowed to manage the Teams App '8782dd91-2afe-45e9-8906-858553f7675c'.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-09-12T21:19:56",
            "request-id": "b50af1b2-b697-403f-b0be-4f66486f4ac1",
            "client-request-id": "b50af1b2-b697-403f-b0be-4f66486f4ac1"
        }
    }
}
```

The request I'm sending:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{USERID}}/teamwork/installedApps
```

Body:

```
    "teamsApp@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/8782dd91-2afe-45e9-8906-858553f7675c"
}
```

What might the issue be? In the developer portal for my app (https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps/), my application client ID for my Teams app is set as the correct Azure app ID, so not sure why it isn't allowed to proactively install the Teams app here.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to successfully make this call in a similar setup, by granting the permission `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadForUser.All` to the Azure AD app **on the client tenant** (the tenant of the Teams user).

##### Update

Sorry in fact the truth is even more crazy than that. Turns out I only get this error when my application requires (and gets) the permission `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForUser.All`.

That's right: by getting one *additional* permission, you have *less* abilities. I guess only Microsoft could pull that one off

##### Original TL;DR

Azure AD apps permissions don't seem to propagate reliably. Re-installing the app on the client tenant(s) may help.

By *install* I mean going to Azure portal as an admin, `Enterprise Applications`, selecting the app, then clicking `Grant admin consent for <...>`.

##### Original Details

For the record, I was getting the same error for another endpoint (trying to list chats). But after the following flow, the call was accepted by Microsoft Graph !

1. removed all the permissions of the Azure AD app
2. the app was still able to list Teams installations in the client tenant
3. added a dummy permission to the app, so I could re-install it on client tenant
4. now the call to list Teams installations was denied by MS Graph
5. added back single permission `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadForUser.All`
6. re-install on client tenant again
7. now both calls (list Teams installations, list chats) work

Good luck

Comment: I had a similar experience. I started with `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForTeam.All`. The [add app to team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-installedapps) API produced a permissions error, so I added `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForTeam.All`. That produced 'AAD App is not allowed to manage the Teams App', so I deleted both permissions, added `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteForTeam.All` again, and waited a few minutes. The API works fine now, with or without `TeamsAppInstallation.ReadWriteSelfForTeam.All`. Thanks for the tip!